# Loopcuts broken on edited cylinders

Tags: modeling

First of all, yes I tried searching for this issue and while a lot of people had this issue, none of the fixes helped me.

I'm trying to make a loop cut on a cylinder, but while it worked on the first cylinder, it's not letting me do that on the second one.
I see yellow dot / dots now instead of the circle.
[image]
I am in edit mode.
I selected the cylinder.
Alt + M didn't help.
I don't see why the edge wouldn't be connected to the mesh, it worked on cylinder one.

I'm lost.

Again, sorry for bringing this topic up again but I didn't find a good solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Alt+M?  You do not want to split the mesh, as it will prevent you from making loop cuts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop Cuts cut across to the opposite edge of a quad (4 sided face / 4 vertex face). When they get to a face with anything other than 4 vertices, it stops.

- This is a Loop Cut dividing an edge instead of faces because it cant find a face to cut over.

[image]

- This is a Loop Cut going all the way around until it gets to the problematic 5 vertex faces.

[image]

Since these extra vertices at the top are not contributing to the shape of the geometry, dissolving them will solve the problem without any side effects. Press <kbd>X</kbd> to bring up the delete menu, select Dissolve Vertices.

[image]

Comment: You sir are a legend.
Thank you for the deteiled explenation of the issue and how to solve it, with graphics and animations.

I'm stunned how someone can give such a useful answer, am really grateful.

I wish you all a nice day, take care.-

- Miko